# Change State when item in Flatlist is long pressed (Functional Components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have got two diffrent functional components; one that renders a flat list (Grid) and another one that is rendered in the Flatlists renderItem (Item). Grid has a state called FanMenuState, when a item in the flatlist is longPressed how would I change the state? I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution

```
function Grid ({data, title}){
 
  const [fanMenuState, setFanMenuState] = React.useState(false);

    return(
        <View style={styles.voltyGrid}>
                  <FlatList
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
                    ListHeaderComponent={()=>
                    <View style={styles.Underline}> 
                      <Text style={styles.introText}>{title}</Text>
                    </View>
                    }
                    numColumns={1}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.voltyItem}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.title} thumbnail={item.thumbnail}/>}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    scrollEnabled={!fanMenuState}
                    
                  />
                </View>      
    )
}
```

This is the second function Item that is rendered in the Flatlist.

```
function Item({ title, thumbnail}) {

    handleLongPress = (event) => {
        
        const posY = event.nativeEvent.pageY;
        const posX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
        console.log(posX)
        //fanMenu(posY, posX)

      };

return(
    <TouchableOpacity  onLongPress={event => handleLongPress(event)}>


            <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.thumbnail}>
            <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={{uri: thumbnail}}/> 
            </View>

            <View style={styles.info}>

                <View style={styles.authorContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.source}>James Dean</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.length}>4 mins</Text>
                </View>

                <View>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{ title }</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.description}>This is the description which could be quite long and explains the content like really long</Text>
                </View>  

                <View style={styles.controlBar}>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.controlBarItem}>
                            <Image style={styles.controlBarItemIcon} source={require('../../Resources/Icons/Like/likeIcon.png')}/>
                            <Text style={styles.controlBarItemText} >0</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.controlBarItem}>
                            <Image style={styles.controlBarItemIcon} source={require('../../Resources/Icons/Comment/Comment.png')}/>
                            <Text style={styles.controlBarItemText} >0</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.controlBarItem}>
                            <Image style={styles.controlBarItemIcon} source={require('../../Resources/Icons/Share/Share.png')}/>
                            <Text style={styles.controlBarItemText} >0</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

            </View>
            </View>

     

    </TouchableOpacity>
    
);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! If you need more information just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
function Grid ({data, title}){
 
  const [fanMenuState, setFanMenuState] = React.useState(false);

  const onChangeState = (data) => {
     console.log(data);
     fanMenuState(…); // change state here …
  }

   return(
        <View style={styles.voltyGrid}>
          <FlatList
             ……            
             renderItem={({item}) => 
              <Item 
                title={item.title} 
                thumbnail={item.thumbnail} 
                onChangeState={onChangeState} //set prop `onChangeState` callback here
              />
             }
            ……
         />
       </View>      
    )
}


// Item.js
function Item({ title, thumbnail, onChangeState}) {

    const handleLongPress = (event) => {
        
        const posY = event.nativeEvent.pageY;
        const posX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
        console.log(posX);
        //fanMenu(posY, posX)

        // call here  like
        const data = { posX , posX }
        onChangeState(data);

    };

    return(
      <TouchableOpacity  onLongPress={event => handleLongPress(event)}>
      …..
      </TouchableOpacity>
    
    );
}
```

Comment: I can see the data being passed correctly, however, I'm using the state to decide whether to disable Flatlist scrolling using ScrollEnabled when an item is long pressed... scrolling doesn't seem to be disabled even though the state is being updated??